# shouldStartLoadWithRequest is not called in my iPhone App

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, event-handling

I have a view controller with a UIWebView controller. I'm trying to get the javascript inside the html content of the web view to pass some information to my objective c code. I came across a number of examples online that set window.location in a javascript function and then catch the event generated by setting the view controller to be the web view's delegate and catching it in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest function. Unfortunately I can't get it to work because for me shouldStartLoadWithRequest is never called even though I'm setting the web view's delegate.

My code is as follows:

The interface:

```
@interface StoryTextViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *storyWebView;   
    NSString *information;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *storyWebView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *information;

@end
```

In the interface, the *information variable is set by the previous view that calls StoryTextViewController.

The implementation:

```
#import "StoryTextViewController.h"

@implementation StoryTextViewController

@synthesize storyWebView;
@synthesize information;

- (NSString *) contructHTMLText
{
    NSString *HTMLText = @"";

    NSArray *words = [information componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *header =
    @"<html>\n"
    "<head>\n"
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"

    "function marktext(theSpanID)\n"
    "{\n"
    "   var theSpan=document.getElementById(theSpanID);\n"
    "   if (theSpan.className == \"noHilite\")\n"
    "   {\n"
    "       theSpan.className = \"hilite\";\n"
    "       window.location = \"true\";\n"
    "   }\n"
    "   else\n"
    "   {\n"
    "       theSpan.className = \"noHilite\";\n"
    "       window.location = \"false\";\n"
    "   }\n"
    "}\n"

    "</script>\n"

    "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"

    ".hilite\n"
    "{\n"
    "   background-color:red;\n"
    "   color:white;\n"
    "   font: bold 60px arial,sans-serif\n"
    "}\n"

    ".noHilite\n"
    "{\n"
    "   background-color:white;\n"
    "   color:black;\n"
    "   font: 60px arial,sans-serif\n"
    "}\n"

    "</style>\n"

    "</head>\n"
    "<body>\n"
    "<div class=\"storyText\">\n";

    NSString *tailer = 
    @"</div>\n"
    "</body>\n"
    "</html>\n";

    HTMLText = [HTMLText stringByAppendingString:header];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [words count]; i ++)
    {
        NSString *tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"   <span id=\"mytext%d\" class=\"noHilite\" onclick=\"marktext(\'mytext%d\')\">%@</span>&nbsp;\n", i, i, (NSString *)[words objectAtIndex:i]];
        HTMLText = [HTMLText stringByAppendingString:tag];
    }
    HTMLText = [HTMLText stringByAppendingString:tailer];
    NSLog(HTMLText);
    return HTMLText;
}

// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        storyWebView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *HTMLData = [self contructHTMLText];
    [storyWebView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @""]];  
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{   
    // handle event here    
    return true;
}

@end
```

Whats happening is that basically, the constructHTML function takes the text inside the *information variable and wraps every word in the text with some html and javascript such that whenever a word is clicked, a css high-lighting is applied on it. What I want to do is to count the number of high-lighted words. I do this by trying to pass something in the function thats called whenever a word is clicked but like i said, the shouldStartLoadWithRequest method thats supposed to be fired is never executed.

I've seen a lot of people do this sort of thing but I cant seem to figure out why its not running for me

Answer (score 4):

You can put breakpoint on setting delegate

```
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
    storyWebView.delegate = self;
}
```

I'm pretty sure storyWebView is nil on that moment.

You can fix it in this manner:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *HTMLData = [self contructHTMLText];
    // empty statement
    // the trick is that if the view is not loaded from the .nib yet
    // it will be loaded and all connections established

    if (self.view);

    // here is setting delegate
    storyWebView.delegate = self;
    [storyWebView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @""]];  
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but it didn't make any difference. self wasn't nil to begin with anyway. Anything else you might suggest?

Comment: self surely will be not nil, what about storyWebView?

Comment: nope. story view displays the html fine too. im completely stumped. if you want maybe i could send you what i coded? my boss is getting a bit impatient and im getting desparate

Comment: You can send it. Use my first name dot second name at gmail dot com

Comment: OK, the real reason of the problem is that you're loading HTML through loadHTMLString

Comment: what is the solution for this. I have same problem. And loading HTML through loadHTMLString

Answer (score 1):

You should set the delegate in `viewDidLoad`, not in `initWithNibName:bundle:`. Alternatively, open up your nib file and control-drag from the web view to your File's Owner, and choose "delegate" from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

- Shouldn't `window.location` be the value of the target URL you are going to? In your `marktext` function you're setting it to `true` or `false`. `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` gets called only when a URL request has been received and is about to go somewhere. Not sure setting the location to a boolean is enough to trigger a navigation event. You can set it to a magic URL then return FALSE from the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` routine if it's asking to navigate to that specific magic URL and prevent it from actually going somewhere. Valid URLs can then be allowed to go through.
- Also might want to take a look at the response to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591949/iphone-webkit-jquery-strangeness-cant-update-content). There may be some timing issues with `window.location`.

Comment: I'm actually trying to set window.locaton to the strings "true" or "false", not that it matters because my code doesn't work for any string. I also looked at the link you sent me but it wasn't what I needed. His problem is that shouldStartLoadWithRequest works TOO well for him where as in my case it doesn't get called at all!

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to set the location value to 'true' or 'false?' That's like typing "http://true" in the URL bar. What happens if you use a valid URL like http://www.stackoverflow.com? My point was I don't think shouldStartLoadWithRequest gets called unless you give it a valid URL to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I also see this problem, because I have set the

```
articleWeb.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`
```

you'd better check your code, set

```
articleWeb.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`
```